# How to retrieve posts from parent category, splitting them per children when displayed?

Tags: categories, wp-query, children

I have a Wordpress database with three categories:

ID 3 : Europe

ID 4 : France (child of 3)

ID 5 : Paris (child of 4)

I now need to display all posts under their respective category, like this:

**EUROPE**

Post 1

Post 2

Post 3

**FRANCE**

Post 1

Post 3

**PARIS**

Post 3

- Post 1 was published under France
- Post 2 was published under Europe
- Post 3 was published under Paris

Can you please confirm I am doing it right like this?

```
<?php
    $args = array('cat' => 3);
    $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<!-- Show EUROPE block, so just loop, no check -->
<?php
    while($category_posts->have_posts()) : $category_posts->the_post();
        the_title("<br />");
    endwhile;
?>          

<!-- Show FRANCE block, check category name -->
<?php
    while($category_posts->have_posts()) : $category_posts->the_post();
        if (strpos(get_the_category()[0]->cat_name,'France') !== false)
            the_title("<br />");
    endwhile;
?>

<!-- Show PARIS block, check category name -->
<?php
    while($category_posts->have_posts()) : $category_posts->the_post();
        if (strpos(get_the_category()[0]->cat_name,'Paris') !== false)
            the_title("<br />");
    endwhile;
?>
```

- HTML formatting omitted from above code.

In poor words, I am calling WP_Query only once and then I loop, checking for the category name "France" and "Paris" for the France and Paris blocks. Is there a better way to do it? Would I cause any performance issues if I call WP_Query three times instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `WP_Query` three times isn't too good for performance, as it will make three queries to the database. The way you're currently approaching this seems like the proper (and fastest) way in may opinion. However, you should be calling `$category_posts->rewind_posts()` after each while-loop to reset `WP_Query`'s loop to the first post.

Furthermore, your current way of checking for a category (like "France") isn't very pretty. WordPress has a function to check whether a post has a term, [`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term), which is perfectly suited for your cause: `has_term( 'France', 'category' )` (you can omit the last parameter, `$post`, as it uses the current post in the loop by default).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is one simple query using [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories). You have the ID's of the three categories, even if they are parent and child categories. You can pass these ID's as with the `include` parameter to only get those three categories, order them by ID and use a `foreach` loop with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get the posts under their respective category

Just remember, when you add the category ID's to the `include` parameter to add them in ascending order. Here is the query, modify as needed

```
<?php 
$categories = get_categories('include=3,4,5&orderby=ID'); //retrieve all the categories and save them as a variable $categories

    foreach($categories as $category) : // Use foreach to split $categories into individual categories and store as variable $category
?>
    <p><?php // Display the category name as a link to the actual category ?>
        Category: <?php echo $category->name ?>
    </p>

<?php
    $catid = $category->cat_ID; //Store the category ID as a variable to be used in WP_Query

    $args = array( 
        'cat' => $catid,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);   

    // Start the Loop. You can use your own loop here
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
    ?>  
        <p> 
            <?php the_title(); //Display only the title of the posts in the category ?> 
        </p>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    endforeach;
?>
```